# Can I use Nearby google API on raspberry running on android things?

Tags: google-api, google-play-services, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am trying to use Nearby API on raspberry pi3 running on google things. I am able to connect to GoogleApliClient but when trying to advertise, the following error has been shown

17: API: Nearby.CONNECTIONS_API is not available on this device.

I am wondering if I can use this api or not.

I found a piano app on GitHub which uses this api on raspberry pi running on a android things. I couldn't figure out how to proceed forward. Please help.

Comment: you need to share code so we can reproduce (or not) your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Nearby is available on Android Things. There are a number of reasons why this may not be present for you.

1. Your system image that you installed does not have Google Play Services.
2. Your app's `build.gradle` is using [the incorrect version](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) of Google Play Services. As of DP6, you should use 11.6.0
3. Your code is doing something that is out-of-date. You can refer to [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) for getting it set up on Android devices. Android Things uses that same API.

If you are looking for another sample, you can look at the official [Robocar](https://github.com/androidthings/robocar) project which also uses the Nearby API.